# load more jquery function that i want

Tags: php, jquery, model-view-controller

i am using MVC and my design for my website is that there is header and body and footer,
every page in my website will have the same header and the same footer, but with different body

and for ever page there is a JS file contains the jquery calls

and for many many pages when it is opening, jquery call works and get data from database using ajax and put that data in that page

my question is : sense the jquery calls begins with `$(document).ready`, so when i open any page, all the jquery call starts, i don't want that, but i want just the jquery for that page which is opening to be loaded

## example

this jquery just for a page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCountries/TRUE",function(data){
        var select = $("#countrySelector");
        var options = '';
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
        }
        select.html("<option>Select Source</option>"+options);
    });
});
```

and this jquery for another page , but it is loaded when i load the first page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Type/getAllTypes/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            options+="<option>Select Type</option>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            $("#addPlace #apTypeSelect").html(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: This question is far too general for us to give you useful answers. Is there a specific instance of code you can share with us?

Comment: @Blazemonger i will but some code

Comment: @Blazemonger i update the question with a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the existence of the elements you're operating on, before you fire off the AJAX method. For instance, in your first example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $("#countrySelector");
    if (select.length) { // must test .length; 'select' always exists even if it's empty
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Cell/getAllCountries/TRUE",function(data){
            var options = '';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            }
            select.html("<option>Select Source</option>"+options);
        });
    }; // end if
});
```

Comment: if i put this $("#addPlace #apConceptSelect").ready(function() after $(document).ready also i have to put ur condition ? or if i just have to put your code when i directly using ajax ?

Comment: The [`.ready` docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) suggest it's not really designed for use with anything except `$(document)`. Just test for the `.length` of the element inside of `$(document).ready` (before running *any* code which applies to the element), and you'll be fine.

Comment: your code works good , thank you man , but i still have a question :) , why when i wrote $(docuemnt).ready(function(){$("#d").ready()}); works for all pages, is it just for the ID "d" ?

Comment: ok ok i got you , sorry i wan not seen your comment, really thank you i accpet your question

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a script to run on a page then either:

1. Don't put it on the page in the first place *or*
2. Wrap it in a conditional that checks if running it would be appropriate for the current page

Comment: In some cases, it doesn't matter. For instance, if you have a `$('.element').each(...)` block, and there are no `.element`s on the page, then the `.each` block will never be run.

Comment: @Quentin i love the second choice but how can that condition be ?

Comment: @Blazemonger — I think that would fall into the category of "a script you don't care about running" rather then "a script you don't want to run".

Comment: @Blazemonger , but when i used $(document).ready , and open JS editor on Google Chrome i can see that all the jQuery function is loaded

Comment: @WilliamKinaan — `if (some_test_that_will_only_be_true_on_the_right_page()) { your_function() }`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan — No. Since (if you fix the missing quote that causes a syntax error), `ready` will fire independently of the number of matches there are for the element. `if (jQuery('#page1').length) { foo(); }` could work though.

Comment: @Quentin what does jQuery('#page1').length do ? is it an identifire for the page?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan — It tests if there are more than 0 elements on the page that match the selector.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan — The answer remains the same.

Comment: @Quentin that is great man , u mean if the page contains at least one items that jquery works on it the function will load , else the function will not load ? am i right ? any way i will test it now ,

Comment: @Quentin i did that but chrome  tells me that still loaded the unwanted juquery calls

Comment: i hope i could be accpet mroe than one answer , i really thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think if you will put all the startup functions  of all pages in document.ready then function will become too lengthy and readability will be effected. You should write different start-up function for each page and call them from page on loading , in this your code will remain simpler e.g.

In js file

```
function InitialFunctionOfPage1()
{//define all prerequisites}

function InitialFunctionOfPage2()
{//define all prerequisites}
```

and in each page you can relevant function on document.ready , ample for page 1

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 InitialFunctionOfPage1();
}
```

Comment: all my problems is that i can't do ur second code , because i have on header for all pages

Comment: No need to put another header on each page , before body (or parent div ) of page put <script> //document.ready for page  </script>  or even you can call InitialFunctionOfPage1() directly in script tag